# Export function only to module test?

Tags: rust

I use the standard way (according to the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-01-writing-tests.html)) to write unit tests:

```
fn func() -> i32 {
    0
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn func_test() {
        let res = func();
    }
}
```

to make it compile, I have to make `func` public via the `pub` keyword.

Is it possible to make `func` private, but use it inside the inner test module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**As of Rust 1.15 your code works without problems!**

Previously only public symbols were imported via a wildcard-import (like `use super::*;`). This behavior changed as specified in [RFC 1560](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1560-name-resolution.md). You can see my full previous answer in the [edit logs](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38168984/4).