# Idiomatic way to test non-public functions

Tags: rust, automated-tests, idioms

This code does not compile with `cargo test`. It gives the error **unresolved** name `bar`

```
fn bar()
{
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test_bar()
    {
        bar();
    }
}
```

Because `fn bar()` is not public. I can get around this by writing my tests this way:

```
fn bar()
{
}

#[cfg(test)]
#[test]
fn test_bar()
{
    bar();
}
```

However, according to the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/testing.html#the-tests-module) the first method is the idiomatic way to write tests in Rust. What is the idiomatic way to test non-public functions in Rust?

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168811/export-function-only-to-module-test/38168984#38168984 - TL;DR for now, use `super::bar`. A yet-to-be-released version of Rust will expand it so that glob imports "just work" in that case.

Comment: Thanks. I've also notice that if I do make bar public, then the compiler no longer gives me a warning that bar() is unused. Is there a way to ensure that tests do not give code the "used" attribute?

Comment: Yes; do not make it public. As http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168811/export-function-only-to-module-test/38168984#38168984 says, you can just `use super::bar;` or call it explicitly `super::bar()`.